# How to base64 encode inputs in React?

Tags: reactjs, post, base64, axios

I am trying to post two inputs with axios and I want to base64 encode them before I send them.

Answer (score 46):

**Deprecated since v6**

`const encodedString = new Buffer('your string here').toString('base64');`

**Use Instead**

`const encodedString = Buffer.from('your string here').toString('base64');`

If you get this error `Uncaught ReferenceError: Buffer is not defined`

you may add dependency on [buffer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/buffer) into your project

`npm install --save buffer`

update your `webpack.config.js`

```js
const webpack = require("webpack");

module.exports = {
    plugins: [
        // add this line to plugins
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            Buffer: ['buffer', 'Buffer'],
        }),
    ],
    resolve: {
        fallback: {
            // add this line to resolve.fallback
            "buffer": require.resolve("buffer")
        }
    },
}
```

Comment: hey and thanks for taking your time! in ('your string here') can i put 2 variables like (username, email) ?

Comment: Oops forgot to ask something. Could I maybe see it in context so I can briefly understand it a bit more? thanks

Comment: encodedString = new Buffer(username + ':' + password).toString('base64');.                  And username and password are strings..

Comment: @vinayverma Tanks for your answer. Can you please tell me how to decode this content on the server-side. I'm using .net as my backend

Comment: This fails now: `Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'buffer' in`...

Answer (score 13):

Consider using [base-64](https://www.npmjs.com/package/base-64) as well which is compatible with `btoa` and `atob`, worked for me in react and react native:

```
npm install base-64 --save
```

```js
import {decode as base64_decode, encode as base64_encode} from 'base-64';
let encoded = base64_encode('YOUR_DECODED_STRING');
let decoded = base64_decode('YOUR_ENCODED_STRING');
```

In case you are using typescript, use `@types/base-64` for typing

```sh
npm i --save-dev @types/base-64
```

Answer (score 7):

Is better you use Buffer.from('Your String').toString('base64'), because new Buffer is deprecated